# JQuery onclick issue when calling a function from the parent page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem..

Actually I do have an issue when sending a value from a child page to the parent page.
I'm actually loading a page via JQuery and that page is getting refreshed to display new results, but one of these problems is that the function from the parent page doesn't get called from the child page.
Although this works perfect on Google Chrome, Opera and Safari, it doesn't seem to work on Firefox.
I heard Firefox doesn't manage events the same way as Safari or Google Chrome does?
I've been searching on answers for this but I couldn't find anything pretty much..

Alright, here's what I'm doing:

The child page calls another file which has all the functions that make my site work, this is what should trigger the function:

```
$like = "<a href='$comment_poster' id='$msgid' class='like' 
         onclick='parent.likecomment(this);'>Like</a>";
echo "$like";
```

And this is the function that gets fired from the onclick event which is located in the parent page (the function is in the parent page the onclick is in the child page):

This function is the one that receives the id from the child page to later on add the value to the database.

```
function likecomment(commentID)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var likeid = commentID.id;
    var author = ($(commentID).attr('href'));

    // forming the queryString
    var data = 'likeid='+ likeid + '&author=' + author;
    if(likeid) 
    {
        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "likeprofmessage.php",
              data: data,
              beforeSend: function(html) 
              { 
                  $(".word").html(likeid);
              },
              success: function(html){ 
                  $("#resultsprofcomments").fadeIn('slow');
                  $('#profcommentsdiv').load('showprofmessages.php?vprofile=<?php echo $row['1'];?>').fadeIn("slow");
                  $("#resultsprofcomments").append(html);
              }
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried the Firefox console and I've received the error: `event is undefined` so this should be a problem on how Firefox manages events.
Again, any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: where is the event variable supposed to be coming from? If this is the entirety of the code, then it shouldn't work because event is undefined

Comment: the "commentID" is getting sent from the onclick event and that id is being taken from "$msgid".

Comment: have you tried with **window.parent.likecomment()**. may this will helpful to you.

Comment: Chandresh, I recently tried that and in Firefox the page just goes to a blank page, I guess this is happening because the onclick event is not calling the function in the parent page which is likecomment(commentID) which has a event.preventdefault(); to prevent these URL's from refreshing the page or displaying a 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following will work as long as you set the onclick handler inline in your HTML (as you did in your example):

```
<A href="..." onclick='parent.likecomment(event,this);'>blah</A>

<SCRIPT>

function likecomment(evt, commentID) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var likeid = commentID.id;
  // etc
}

</SCRIPT>
```

For event handlers *not* set inline in HTML, the standards compliant browsers (including FF) should automatically pass the event object as a parameter to your handler function. IE, up to version 8, anyway, uses a different event model and lets you reference `event` directly - really it is `window.event` but generally as with most window properties it works even if you omit `window.`.

So if you assign your click handler on document ready (or onload) you can do this:

```
function yourOnloadFunction() {
  document.getElementById('yourElementId').onclick = clickHandler;
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  // check if event object was passed in, otherwise use window.event
  if (!e) e = window.event;

  // but how to get a reference to the clicked element?
  // use the event object's target property, except (of course)
  // in IE, which uses srcElement:

  var elRef = e.srcElement ? e.srcElement : e.target;

  // rest of your function here, e.g.
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you sir are a genius.
I actually forgot to set the event handler in my function and onclick.
Thank you all for your help, this question is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have managed to make a mess of your code, but try to change

```
onclick='parent.likecomment(this);'
```

to

```
onclick='parent.likecomment(this);return false;'
```

and then remove

```
event.preventDefault();
```

from your function `likecomment(commentID)`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the in-line onClick, have you tried sending back a script that does something like

```
<Script>$('#{id}').click(function() { 
    var id = this.id;
    likecomment(id);
    return false;
})</Script>
```

Comment: Anthony, I've tried that and it didn't seem to work, thank you anyways.

Comment: Didn't seem to work how? What does it show in the Firebug? My solution is what I used to solve similar scenario.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know who rated your answer down but it wasn't me.
I basically tried the code and all I got was the same as with the onclick event, it just wouldn't work, from firebug I would get this:

[02:53:39.517] uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #{id}
[02:53:39.537] syntax error @ http://shoopthere.com/shoopthere/logged.php:869
[02:53:39.569] missing } after property list @ http://shoopthere.com/shoopthere/logged.php:1118