# Setting the selected value of a tree view in parent page onclick of a hyperlink in the child page

Tags: c#, javascript, treeview

I have a TreeView in the parent page onclick of a hyper link in the child page i want to change the selected node of the tree view can somebody tell me how this can be done? i am kinda new to this.

Comment: tumhi kay prayatna kelat to pan liha na.

Comment: i am sorry i don understand your language

Comment: ohh, i though you are marathi speaking person.(Due to your sirname Kapse).

Comment: actually my native is sholapur but unfortunately i have not learnt the language

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery for this purpose.

Refer following lnik that might guid you.

[JQuery onclick issue when calling a function from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646068/jquery-onclick-issue-when-calling-a-function-from-the-parent-page)